# Seeding database with random states in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel 8 application and I want to be able to seed one of my tables with different states when I execute `php artisan db:seed`. Here's an example table:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `recipient_role` enum('Manager','Employee') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Manager',
  `recipient_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `notifications_recipient_id_foreign` (`recipient_id`),
  KEY `notifications_sender_id_foreign` (`sender_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `notifications_recipient_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`recipient_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `notifications_sender_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sender_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

In this particular case, I want to create several `Notification` instances using `Notification::factory` where `is_read` is random set to `1` OR `0`. I also would like to make sure that two random `User` instances are selected (they will be seeded first) for the `recipient_id` and `sender_id`. This means I cannot hard code them into my Factory.

In the actual factory I only have `message` being filled in:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Notification;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class NotificationFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Notification::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
            'message' => $this->faker->sentence,
            
        ];
    }
}
```

My question is, in the `NotificationSeeder.php` definition, how do I ensure that I have a random `is_read` state and two different users assigned to `recipient_id` and `sender_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with Laravel 8, but I think it should work:

NotificationFactory:

```php
public function definition()
{
    // Get 2 random users IDs
    $users = User::inRandomOrder()->take(2)->pluck('id');

    return [
        'message'      => $this->faker->sentence,
        'is_read'      => rand(0, 1),
        'recipient_id' => $users->first(),
        'sender_id'    => $users->last(),
    ];
}
```

If you create the users first, then just get 2 random users. I did 1 call to get 2 users instead of 1 call per user. That returns a collection of users IDs, get the first one for "recipient_id" and the last one to "sender_id".

Answer (score 0):

Use faker's numberBetween function to get a random number between 0-1.
https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderbase

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Notification;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class NotificationFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Notification::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
            'message' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'is_read' => $this->faker->numberBetween(0, 1),
            
        ];
    }
}
```

Then when you're creating the notifications, first create your user's, then provide them to the make/create method.

```
// create two users
$first = User::factory()->count(1)->create();
$second = User::factory()->count(1)->create();

// override the default notification attributes with the user's id
$notification = Notification::factory()->count(1)->create([
        'recipient_id' => $first->id,
        'sender_id' => $second->id,
]);
```

Comment: Is it a better practice to re-create users, as you did above in the notification seeder, even though I already seeded the database with them in a previous seed class?

Comment: @randombits I don't know the amount of data you are seeding, but make a test to see if there is any difference between the two approaches. I prefer, whenever is possible, to not re-seed tables from another seeders. Just to keep track of which one is doing what.